# Only site directories are showing and not the site - I suspect I need a correct .htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This is what I have in my root folder, and when I go to my url, this is what is showing and not my website. It is a wordpress site, only structured a little different. (roots.io/composer)
[This is the root folder: www.mysite.com (I know the site works, I tested it on another web hosting server.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o5Ry.png)

Inside the folder 'public_html' is the index.php file. And if I click it I go to the site, but it looks like this: [/public_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAzZi.jpg)

Only site directories are showing and I suspect I need a working .htaccess file.. Anyone?
/public_html

And so I have a hunch that I need the correct .htaccess file in order to find the correct folders and files. Or am I wrong?

Some other details:

- In the browser I use a 'working-url': new.mysite.com because the main url is routed to another webhost until we get the new site up and running. But the files are inside the root folder. (Not mysite.com/new)
- I've set the siteurl to: https://example.com/wp
- And homeurl to: https://example.com

I've tried writing a .htaccess file like this, but getting the 500 internal error message:

```
#This is for subdirectory
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URO} !public_html/
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/$1 [L]

#This is must
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried a lot of things, but can't seem to find the connecting dots. If someone out there with a clear head and more experience that could look into this, I would highly appreciated it.
Kind regards,
Me